# Add command in visual studio 2010 and make it stay

Tags: visual-studio-2010, customization

In Visual Studio 2010, I'm adding a command by going `tools -> customize -> commands`. However, the changes I make there appear to be temporary. After I open Visual Studio another time, my command is not there.

How do I add a command so that it stays?

Comment: This should have worked... Does the change stick if you run VS as an administrator (assuming Win7/Vista)?

Comment: @eran - toda.It works when done as administrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem probably comes from VS not having permissions to modify its settings, when running as a non-administrator, due to UAC limitations. I actually don't have this problem - on my Win7, VS10 settings stick even when running as regular user, but this might be an issue with specific installation settings.

Bottom line, running VS as administrator should remove the permissions limitations, and allow VS to store the modified settings properly.